# Right way to do pointer arithematic

Tags: c, pointers

I have below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct cache_malloc {
    int     size;
    int     flags;
    struct cache_malloc *fwd;
    struct cache_malloc *bak;
} cache_malloc_t;

int main()
{
  cache_malloc_t cmp;
  cache_malloc_t *new = &cmp;
  new->size = 10;
  new->flags = 1;
  
  printf("======without Arithematic======\n");
  printf("(char *)new = %p \n",  (((char *)new)));
  printf("(void *)new = %p \n",  (((void *)new)));
  printf("(int *)new = %p \n",  (((int *)new)));

  printf("======with Arithematic======\n");
  printf("(char *)new = %p \n",  ((((char *)new)+ 26)));
  printf("(void *)new = %p \n",  ((((void *)new)+ 26)));
  printf("(int *)new = %p \n",  ((((int *)new) + 26)));

  return 0;
}
```

Output looks as shown below

```
======without Arithematic======
(char *)new = 0xffd65dcc 
(void *)new = 0xffd65dcc 
(int *)new = 0xffd65dcc 
======with Arithematic======
(char *)new = 0xffd65de6 
(void *)new = 0xffd65de6 
(int *)new = 0xffd65e34
```

Without pointer arithmetic, all the address are same however I get different address when I do pointer arithmetic.

What is the right way to do pointer arithmetic?

The exact problem I'm facing here is I have the below code.

```
cache_malloc_t *cmp;
cache_malloc_t *cmp2;
cmp2 = (cache_malloc_t *)((int32)cmp + cmp->size + sizeof(cm_cache_malloc_t));
cmp2->size = save; // I got a core dump at this line
```

To fix the same I tried modifying the code as shown below.

```
cmp2 = (cache_malloc_t *)((int32 *)cmp + cmp->size + sizeof(cm_cache_malloc_t)); //Still resulted in core dump
cmp2 = (cache_malloc_t *)((char *)cmp + cmp->size + sizeof(cm_cache_malloc_t)); //Worked fine absoultely
```

With the sample code i got to know that address is being changed in int32* casting as compared with char* casting.

Comment: Because you cast the pointer to `int*` and 1 unit in pointer arithmetic is the size of the type pointed to. Like with array indexing: one unit takes the memory size of the type. And `new[1]` is the same as `*(new+1)`.

Comment: Also note that pointer arithmetic with `void*` is not in the standard C.

Comment: There is no abstract "right way to do pointer arithmetic". There might be a way to do pointer arithmetic so that it solves your specific problem. What is your specific problem?

Comment: Thank you all for the response, I updated the exact problem which I'm facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `printf`s invoke undefined behaviour (UB) as you need to cast to `void *` if you use `%p`

```
type *ptr;
type *ptr1 = ptr + x;
```

When you do pointer arithmetic the number you are adding is related to the type of the pointer. So the actual address difference (in `char`s) will be `sizeof(type) * x`

```
typedef struct cache_malloc {
    int     size;
    int     flags;
    struct cache_malloc *fwd;
    struct cache_malloc *bak;
} cache_malloc_t;

int main()
{
  cache_malloc_t cmp;
  cache_malloc_t *new = &cmp;
  new->size = 10;
  new->flags = 1;
  
  printf("======without Arithematic======\n");

  printf("======with Arithematic======\n");
  printf("(char *)new = %p \n",  (void *)((((char *)new)+ 26)));
  printf("(double *)new = %p \n",  (void *)((((double *)new)+ 26)));
  printf("(int *)new = %p \n",   (void *)((((int *)new) + 26)));

  uintptr_t uptr = (uintptr_t) new;

  printf("======test======\n");
  printf("char   %zx \n",  uptr + 26 * sizeof(char));
  printf("double %zx \n",  uptr + 26 * sizeof(double));
  printf("int    %zx \n",  uptr + 26 * sizeof(int));

  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jffxqYKr5

Comment: "All your printfs invoke undefined behaviour (UB)"  --> OP's `printf("(void *)new = %p \n",  (((void *)new)));` looks fine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica indeed, BTW his code will not compile usin non gcc family compiler as he uses arithmetic on void pointers

Comment: Other compilers too will do `void *` "math", yet any of those is outside the C spec.

Comment: There might be some wiggle room on `printf("(char *)new = %p \n",  (((char *)new)));` being OK too, given there is something about `void *` and `char *` using like encoding, but not worth the research.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1.

Comment: It is not a size issue, but a pointer encoding one and `...` function passing one.

Answer (score 3):

> Without pointer arithmetic, all the address are same however I get different address when i do pointer arithmetic.

C uses the base type of the pointer to to calculate the offset. A `char` has a size of 1, so adding 26 to a pointer of type `char *` adds (1 * 26) to the address in the pointer. An `int` has a size of (say) 4, so adding 26 to an `int *` adds (4 * 26). You get different addresses because you're casting the pointer to different types with different sizes.

> What is the right way to do pointer arithmetic?

The right way is to omit the casts; in general, it doesn't make sense to cast a pointer to a different type before using it in calculations, because you're not changing the size or type of the values in memory.

Comment: "adds (1 * 26) to the address in the pointer." --> not always.  This assumes a certain (yet common) pointer/memory model.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the right way to do pointer arithmetic?

- Stop casting.  (Cast to `void *` for printing a reasonable exception.)
- Do not attempt `+`, `-` on `void *` pointers.
- OK to use math on `(u)intptr_t` integers, just do not expect code can reliably convert that integer into a valid pointer.  `(u)intptr_t` not needed at all to do *pointer arithmetic* or even print a pointer's value.
- Only use  `+`, `-` that result in a pointer within (or one past) the same object (e.g. arrays).

```
int a;
int *p = &a;
printf("%p\n", (void*) &a);
printf("%p\n", (void*) p);
printf("%p\n", (void*) (&a + 1));
printf("%p\n", (void*) (p + 1));
// Not OK
printf("%d\n", p[1]);  // Not OK to de-reference `p + 1`.
```

```
int b[100];
int *q = &b[50];
printf("%p\n", (void*) &b);
printf("%p\n", (void*) q);
printf("%p\n", (void*) (&b + 100));
printf("%p\n", (void*) (q + 50));
printf("%p\n", (void*) (q - 50));
// Not OK
printf("%p\n", (void*) (q + 51));
printf("%p\n", (void*) (q - 51));
printf("%d\n", q[100]);  // Not OK to de-reference `p + 1`.
```